# Equation of a tangent that passes through a point not on the curve

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, quadratics

Just made this little question for me and a friend and we couldn't find the answer given what we know, which is only fairly basic calculus, similar to what you would learn in the first year of 'A level' maths.

> Find the equation of the line which is a tangent to the curve $x^2-2x-1$ and passes through the point $(5,5)$.

I can find the gradient of the curve at $x$ of $2x-2$ fairly easily, and I know that the line $y=mx+c$ will have a gradient $m$ which is equal to $2x-2$ at the point where they intersect, but I don't know how to form an equation given this.

Any simple explanation of how to answer this would be greatly appreciated.

Here is a visualisation of the problem:
[Image captured on an graphing calculator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5zLxG.png)

The red curve is the quadratic I described and the blue is the tangent I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to the tangent line at what point??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Using your approach, note that ,if $Q=(x_Q,y_Q)$ is the point of tangency than the slope of the line is:
$$
m=\frac{y_Q-5}{x_Q-5}
$$

Since $Q$ is point of the parabola, we have $y_Q=x_Q^2-2x_Q-1$, and we want that this slope is the same as the derivative of the function at $x_Q$, so we have the equation:

$$
\frac{f(x_Q)-5}{x_Q-5}=f'(x_Q)
$$
that is:
$$
\frac{x_Q^2-2x_Q-1-5}{x_Q-5}=2x_Q-2
$$

solve this equation and find $x_Q$, so you can find the point $Q$ and the slope of the tangent.

But you  can use also another approach that does not require derivatives.

The lines passing for the given point are:
$$
y-5=m(x-5)
$$
and we want the line that is tangent to the parabola, this means that this line has only one common point with the parabola, so, write the system:
$$
\begin {cases}
y-5=m(x-5)\\
y=x^2-2x-1
\end{cases}
$$
and find for what values of $m$ it has only one solution, i.e. for what $m$ the discriminant of the system is equal to 0. This is the slope of the tangent.

Comment: Where do I find the discriminant in that system, do I rearrange until I find an equation that is just f(x) with some terms involving m and then set the discriminant of that equal to 0? i.e. x^2-2x-1-(m(x-5)+5)=0

Answer (score 0):

HINT.
$$
{y-5\over x-5}=m=2x-2.
$$

Comment: Thanks, just ended up solving x^2-10x+16=0 from rearranging that. It gives the solutions x=2, and x=8. How do I work out that the solution at x=8 won't be valid , but x=2 will (i.e. one of them is the tangent, and the other only has the same gradient at the same x co-ordinate, but does not intersect the curve)

Comment: Would it be best to show the discriminant of the equation x^2-2x-1-(2x-5)=0 to show it's a tangent? Could i have used this known fact to determine the equation of the tangent only at an earlier stage i.e.  substitute values for b^2-4ac=0 ?

Comment: Yes, that is another way to do the same thing. As for the two solutions, they are both valid: from a point outside a parabola you can draw two tangent lines.

Comment: Sorry i did some rearranging wrong, found the other equation to be y=14x-65

Answer (score -1):

You should try and understand what the equation of a line means. Consider the following:

$$y - y_1 = m(x - x_1)$$

What this equation is telling you is that for every movement of $(x - x_1)$ on the x-axis we go up or down by $(y - y_1)$ on the y-axis. The value $m$ (i.e. the slope) is like a tuning variable that controls how quickly you go up or down and you can obtain this value using the derivative.

If you understand this then solving the problem is pretty simple. Just note that you can obtain the point $(x_1, y_1)$ using the original equation

Comment: OK so do I simply have to substitute 'y' with x^2-2x-1 , 'y1' with 5, 'x1' with 5 and m with 2x-2 ?

Comment: No, you should watch [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra-basics/core-algebra-graphing-lines-slope/core-algebra-equation-of-a-line/v/equation-of-a-line-1) video if you still don't understand. If you perform that substitution you will not have an equation of a line. The key is to recognize that you can get $y_1$ from the original equation (ie $x^2 - 2x - 1$) by inputing $x_1$ (ie 5) into the equation,

Comment: I do know how to find the equation of a line given a gradient and a point, but I don't know the point that the line intersects the curve. I know that i can find that point by finding the X value that they intersect, then plugging it back into the equation of the curve, and that's the part of the problem i can't do.

Comment: The gradient is the normal for the line. Therefore if you have a point $p = (x_0,y_0)$ on the line then you want $(x,y)$ such that $ \langle x - x_0, y-y_0 \rangle \cdot \nabla f(p) = 0$. If you respond to my comment, I can help you! When you mention a tangent line, that is a linear approximation to the graph of a function at a point, you never said for which point do you want to put the tangent line at. To get the point of intersection, just set the two equations equal to each other and solve.

Comment: If $x = 5$ then the point that is on the curve at this point is $(5)^2 - 2(5) - 1$

Comment: It's probably best you have a look at my link to a visualisation, I'm looking for the equation of the blue line. I found from trial and error that the line and the curve intersect at x=2, so the gradient is 2 and the equation of the line is 2x-5 (Would be useful for someone to give me at least the first step of how to get there :s)

Comment: I've made a mistake, I apologize. Did not look at the picture and the shifted point of intersection. Lots of other answers now though